# Run MSBuild script once for solution

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have got a solution with 30 projects. All these projects have the same custom MSBuild script which copies all the compiled files (from the _PackageTempDir) to another location on the hard drive.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <DeployFilesBin Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(DeployFilesBin)" DestinationFiles="@(DeployFilesBin->'$(DeployDestinationBin)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SkipUnchangedFiles="True" />
```

When I change the name of a file, this file will not be removed from the destination directory which is unwanted because I could get an ambiguous reference exception.
I do not want a global MSBuild script because I would like to use Visual Studio's build shortcut for executing csproj files.

Is there any way to delete all files in the destination directory and then execute all csproj files? Maybe a target which is fired once of a way to declare a global variable to check if that specific cleanup target has already ran?

Comment: It looks like this can not be done. I fixed my problem with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511706/msbuild-delete-files-older-6-months. All files older than 5 minutes will be deleted during my MSBuild script.